# Where can I find a list of events triggered by MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, events, mongodb

I'd like to use MongoDB in client side (javascript) but I would need to attach to it a lot of events listener (before/after : create,update,delete, etc).

Is MongoDB working with events ? How can I find a documentation about that?

I tried to search for "[MongoDB events](https://www.google.fr/search?q=mongodb%20events)" in google, but I can only find "Public real life" events.

Comment: There are no triggers! Point.

Comment: Oh that's sad :/ Any reason why?

Comment: Apparently, nobody needed them so badly that it would make oneself design and implement this piece of functionality :)

Comment: Look into client-side higher-level frameworks sometimes providing such a functionality on the application level

Comment: You mean like SpineJs, EmberJs, BackboneJs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have triggers. You can hack together your own solution, but it will only have after-"triggers".

This involves building a replica set (if you don't have one yet) and reading replication [oplog](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Oplog). Remember, replica set can consist of just one member.